# openssl outform verson 3 vs 1.1

Tags: openssl

I'm trying to use openssl to create a certificate and a private key from pfx file. Should be a simple enough operation. But I'm getting stuck on the private key creation.
It has to be in a PVK format (Microsoft). Which should be handled by rsa -outform PVK. like this:

```
openssl rsa -in test.pem -outform PVK -out test.pvk
```

which works in version 1.1 but not in 3.0.
in 3.0 it gives an error about

> inner_evp_generic_fetch:unsupported:crypto\evp\evp_fetch.c:341:Global
> default library context, Algorithm (RCA: 26), Properties ().

I found some posts saying that I need to use the `-provider legacy` option. But that just gives me a different error:

```
inner_loader_fetch:unsupported:crypto\store\store_meth.c:353:No store loader found
```

I suppose I can continue using 1.1, but how can I make it work with 3.0?

Comment: The error is on RC4 not RCA. You need _both_ `-provider legacy -provider default` (in either order), or to change the config file to load both. But either way this is not programming or development.

Comment: are you suggesting to use two providers?

Comment: Exactly. You need the legacy provider for RC4, AND the default provider for 'store' functionality now used by key-handling subcommands.

Comment: I'll test it. You should make your comment into an answer.

Comment: it worked. thanks!